# TypeError when using torch.autograd.profiler.profile

Tags: pytorch, profiler

I am trying to analyze memory consumption for my model as described here:
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/profiler_recipe.html

using these lines:

```
with profiler.profile(profile_memory=True, record_shapes=True) as prof:
    tubes, _, _ = zip(*model(imgs, img_metas, return_loss=False))
print(prof.key_averages().table(sort_by="self_cpu_memory_usage", row_limit=10))
```

but I get this error

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument
> 'profile_memory'

So, what would be the reason and/or the solution for this error?

Comment: Can you include complete code in the question

Comment: What is the PyTorch version you're using?

Comment: pytorch 1.1.0,  py3.7_cuda10.0.130_cudnn7.5.1_0

Comment: For including the complete code, I think it's irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade your version of PyTorch. Looking at [the code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/autograd/profiler.py), one can see that the `profile_memory` argument was added to the function signature first in PyTorch v1.6.0.

You can also see this through the documentation of `torch.autograd`. You can see that the argument is not present in [PyTorch v1.1.0](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.1.0/autograd.html#torch.autograd.profiler.profile).